# Netbeans 8.2 all projects broken, no JDK found

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8, netbeans-8

I recently switched to Linux Mint, and needed to install Netbeans version 8.2. It installed without issue, but whenever I try to open a project, its marked as broken. I did some searching, and it seems that it isn't recognizing the JDK I installed (jdk 1.8.0_131). I tried to do some troubleshooting myself, but I can't find a way to fix it. I was hoping someone here could lead me in the right direction. Please let me know if you need more info.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you added java to the system/user path? Have you exported the JAVA_HOME environment variable?

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit more? I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to Linux, but I am relatively comfortable with the command line, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you did not install jdk correctly for your system. Simple solution may be to edit netbeans.conf file (in installation folder in etc subfolder) and define netbeans_jdkhome. You can find a row starting with netbeans_jdkhome in the bottom of the file commented by #.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'll take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

While installing NetBeans 8.2 on Ubuntu 18.04, there was one question about NetBeans jdk installation path, specify correct path there about JAVA_HOME.
In my case the was taken as `"/usr"`.
After changing  netbeans_jdkhome as `"/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"` in netbeans.conf in `netbeans-8.2rc/etc`, all worked fine.